# just by looking at the graph of the density function can you determine if the expected value is finite or infinite?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

for example can you conclude that the expected value of $Z$ is infinite just by looking at the graph?

$$f_Z(z) =
\begin{cases}
{\dfrac{\ln(z)}{z^2}},  & \text{for $z \ge 1$} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{for $z \lt 1$}
\end{cases}$$

[here](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/functions-graphing-calculator/%5Cfrac%7Bln%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%7D%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%7D/?origin=enterkey) is the graph

Comment: Usually, it's hard to tell by looking at a graph because heavy tails are hard to spot.  Think of it like telling the divergence of the harmonic series just by looking.  In your example, you would integrate to get the expectation (and it would work well after a $u$-substitution).

Comment: Not really. $f(x)=\begin{cases} x^{-2} & x \in [1,\infty) \\ 0 & x \not \in [1,\infty) \end{cases}$ and $g(x)=\begin{cases} 1.01 x^{-2.01} & x \in [1,\infty) \\ 0 & x \not \in [1,\infty) \end{cases}$ look essentially the same.

Comment: This is indeed a nice question ;) I recommend you to link your previous question so people make sure that the problem of computing the limit was already solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking by the graph is never sufficient. Pick $a < -1$. Then
$$
\int_1^{\infty} x^a \, dx = \left. \frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1} \right|_1^{\infty} = \frac {-1}{a+1}
$$
(note that $a < -1$ means $a+1 < 0$, so that the above fraction denotes a positive area under a positive curve) but for $a=-1$, 
$$
\int_1^{\infty} \frac 1x \, dx = \left. \phantom{\int} \hspace{-12 pt} \log(x) \right|_1^{\infty} = \infty. 
$$
You could argue that for $a$ close to $-1$, a finite portion of the graph of $x^a$ will look extremely similar to the graph of $x^{-1}$, so you cannot come to any relevant conclusions with just a picture.

In your case, letting $u = \log x$, $du = \frac 1x dx$, we have
$$
\int_1^{\infty} x \frac{\log x}{x^2} \, dx = \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\log x}x \, dx = \int_0^{\infty} u \, du = \left. \frac{u^2}2 \right|_0^{\infty} = \infty. 
$$

Hope that helps,

Comment: It would be nice to see an example where two legitimates PDF's are involved but the mean of one of them is undefined.  That would be a more interesting comparison in terms of the OP's question.

Comment: @Carlos Mendoza : Undefined? PDFs are positive, thus their expectation over the interval $[0,\infty[$ is alwas either finite or infinite. Are you interested in variables with support including the negative side? Because that is not suggested by the OP's question.

Comment: Take the [Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Explanation_of_undefined_moments) distribution as an example.

Answer (score 1):

Although not an answer to the OP, I feel like the expectation of the example should be computed.

$$
\mathbb{E}(Z)=\int_1^\infty z\cdot f_Z(z)dz=\int_1^\infty z\cdot\frac{\ln(z)}{z^2}dz=\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(z)}{z}dz
$$
With a $u$-substitution, where $u=\ln(z)$ and $du=\frac{1}{z}$, this equals
$$
\int_0^\infty udu
$$
which diverges.